# FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to the same file: Is a read() guaranteed to see all write()s that "happened before"?

Tags: java, concurrency, stream

I am using a file as a cache for big data. One thread writes to it sequentially, another thread reads it sequentially.

Can I be sure that all data that has been written (by `write()`) in one thread can be `read()` from another thread, assuming a proper "happens-before" relationship in terms of the Java memory model? Is this behavior documented?

In my JDK, `FileOutputStream` does not override `flush()`, and `OutputStream.flush()` is empty. That's why I'm wondering...

The streams in question are owned exclusively by a class that I have full control of. Each stream is guaranteed to be accesses by one thread only. My tests show that it works as expected, but I'm still wondering if this is guaranteed and documented.

See also [this related discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17598/discussion-between-hussain-al-mutawa-and-user946850).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are using a posix file system, then yes.

`FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` on *nix use the read and write system calls internally.  The documentation for write says that [reads will see the results of past writes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html),

> After a write() to a regular file has successfully returned:
>
> Any successful read() from each byte position in the file that was
>   modified by that write shall return the data specified by the write()
>   for that position until such byte positions are again modified.

I'm pretty sure ntfs on windows will have the same `read()` `write()` guarantees.

Comment: Where can I look up how `FileInputStream.read()` and `FileOutputStream.write()` are implemented?

Comment: You can start here, http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c

Comment: Not entirely correct, as spteams can use internal buffers and don't call OS write right away

Answer (score 5):

You can't talk about "happens-before" relationship in terms of the Java memory model between  your `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` objects since they don't share any memory or thread. VM is free to reorder them just honoring your synchronization requirements. When you have proper synchronization between reads and writes without application level buffering, you are safe.

However `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` share a file, which leaves things up to the OS which in main stream ones you can expect to read after write in order.

Comment: If I consider x=`write()` and y=`read()` for the definition of happens-before and synchronizes-with (§§ 17.4.4 and 17.4.5 of the Java 5 specs), how is a sharing of memory between x and y required? Please elaborate.

Comment: (added thread clarifitcation) If you have two different objects in two different threads VM is free to put them in any order according to 'base' rules you mentioned in Java spec. If one wants to add extra rules, he/she uses synchronization mechanism but then spec. doesn't have to say anything about it being an object wrapping file system operations.

Answer (score 1):

If FileOutputStream does not override flush(), then I think you can be sure all data written by write() can be read by read(), unless your OS does something weird with the data (like starting a new thread that waits for the hard drive to spin at the right speed instead of blocking, etc) so that it is not written immediately.

Comment: Obviously, yes. But that's precisely what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to flush() the Streams (at least for Buffered(Input|Output)Streams), otherwise you could have data in a buffer.

Maybe you need a [concurrent data structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)?

Comment: See my edit. Please assume that write "happens before" read, and this is guaranteed using suitable synchronization primitives.

Comment: Depends on what you use to read the file, there could be some buffering too... If you use a BufferedInputStream, there is a possibility that you miss the update. Concurrent data structures could be better in that case...

Comment: I'm using a plain FileInputStream and FileOutputStream, without buffering.