# Two streams and one file

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io, outputstream

What will happen if I create two instances of class FileInputStream and FileOutputStream using the default constructor and as an argument specify the same path and file name like this..

```
 FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("SomePath/file.txt");  
 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("SamePath/file.txt");
```

Let's imagine that we have a few strings inside the file "file.txt". Next, using a loop I am trying to read bytes from the file.txt and write them into the same file.txt each iteration, like this:

```
 while (is.available()>0){
      int data = is.read();
      os.write(data);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
```

The problem is that when I am trying to run my code, all text from the file.txt just erasing. What happens when two or more streams trying to work with the same file? How does Java or the file system work with such a situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to the same file: Is a read() guaranteed to see all write()s that "happened before"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741937/fileinputstream-and-fileoutputstream-to-the-same-file-is-a-read-guaranteed-to)

Comment: They're not the same file - the paths in your code snippet are different.

Comment: And if they are the same file, why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: No no, they have the same path, somePath equal samePath

Comment: So what exactly is the point of copying the file onto itself? If you merely removed all this code from your application it would work better than it does now.

Comment: Nice joke, dude
why so much hating?

Comment: yes,  absolutely no point of copying the file onto itself, but
following this idea it should just iterate through the while loop forever since is.available()>0 condition would be always true, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your operating system. On Windows the `new FileOutputStream(...)` will probably fail. On Unix-line systems you will get a new file while the old one continues to be readable.

However your copy loop is invalid. `available()` is not a test for end of stream, and it's not much use for other purposes either. You should use something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Why available() is not a test for end of stream?
Available() show as how many bit is left in the file, am I right? ..

Comment: No, you're wrong. See the Javadoc. It is an *estimate* of how much data is present to be read *without blocking.* It can be zero any time, or all the time in some implementations: not just at end of stream.