# increase in file size after transfer across socket

Tags: java, file, sockets

I`m create a programm for transfer file across sockets. After save a file its size is increase. Here is the source code Server-class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FileServer {
 static final int port = 3000;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
         Socket client = server.accept();
         DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
         int size = 2358464;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

         while (true) {
             int receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);
             if (receivedBytes == -1) break;
         }

         input.close();
         client.close();
         server.close();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Projects\\Courses\\loadedFile.s3db");
         fos.write(buffer);
         fos.close();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
     }
 }}
```

Client-class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         final int port = 3000;
         try {
             File file = new File("D:\\Projects\\Courses\\src\\Data", "data.s3db");

             FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
             int size = (int) file.length();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

             Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
             DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

             while (true) {
                 int receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);
                 if (receivedBytes == -1) {
                     break;
                 }
                 if (receivedBytes > 0) {
                     out.write(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
                 }
             }

             input.close();
             out.close();
             socket.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

As a result, a file, which originally had a size of 6 kb, after the transfer, began to weigh 2304 kb. At what stage does the file size increase? How can this be avoided?

Comment: Maybe an issue with encoding? Or block sizes on the file system? Did you compare the contents of the two files?

Comment: your client respects the number of bytes received and does invoke `write(buf, start, offset)` while the server just calls `write(buffer)` causing it to write all 2358464 allocated bytes (2304 kB). Opening the file should show all ZERO bytes beyond initial 6kB.

Comment: The contents of the file are the same. How can I avoid writing blank bytes? Find out the size of the file in the client and pass it to the server or use some method inside the server to ignore the empty bytes?

Comment: On the server, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537851/238704) standard copy loop to read data from the socket and write it out to a file. Or even easier, just use the [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)

Comment: Thanks all, now the program works correctly. I'm used the first link, which gave from James.