# Can I make FileInputStream.read block until FileOutputStream on the same file is closed?

Tags: java, concurrency, eof, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In my application I am receiving data which I want to store in a file and also do some calculations with it. Both receiving and calculating may last long so I want to do it asyncronous.
The listing below shows my basic setup: `thread1` produces some data and stores them in a file.
`thread2` reads the file and processes the data.

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread( () -> {
      try {
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( "test" ) );
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
          //producing data...
          out.write( ( "hello " + i + "\n" ).getBytes() );
          out.flush();
          //Thread.sleep( 10 );
        }
        out.close();
      } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } );
    thread1.start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread( () -> {
      try {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( "test" ) );
        int b = in.read();
        while( b != -1 ) {
          //do some calculation with data
          System.out.print( (char)b );
          b = in.read();
        }
        in.close();
      } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } );
    thread2.start();
```

I guess reading and writing simultaneously on the same file is ok according to this question: [FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to the same file: Is a read() guaranteed to see all write()s that "happened before"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741937/fileinputstream-and-fileoutputstream-to-the-same-file-is-a-read-guaranteed-to) or an I missing something here?

Executing the listing above produces an output as expected:

```
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 4
hello 5
hello 6
hello 7
hello 8
hello 9
```

But if the reader thread is for some reason faster than the writer (can be simulated by uncommenting the Thread.sleep line in thread1) the reader reads a *EOF* (-1) and finishes before the file is completely written. Only one line is put out:

```
hello 0
```

However the writer still produces the entire output in "test" file.

Now I would like to make `in.read()` block until the FileOutputStream in thread1 is closed. 
I thought this can be done by avoiding that *EOF* is put at the end of the file until  `out` is closed. Is that true and if yes, how can I do that? Or are there better approaches?

Comment: No you can't. You should pass the data to, or through, the reading code while you are writing it.

Comment: If you want a pipe, you should use a pipe…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reader (consumer) can wait on a writer (producer), even if the interface is a file. But in general, you would be much better off using a queue and following the producer/consumer pattern.

Anyway, in this case, a crude "wait for more input" procedure involves just two `Atomic` values:

- one to keep track of the number of bytes written (`AtomicInteger`)
- one to indicate that no more bytes are available (`AtomicBoolean`)

Atomic variables can be shared between threads: both threads will always see the latest value of the atomic value.
The writer can then update the number of bytes written via an `AtomicInteger` and the reader can then decide to wait for more input.
The writer can also indicate if no more bytes will be written via an `AtomicBoolean` and the reader can use that information to read to the end of the file.

Another thing to keep in mind is that starting a thread is not in your control: your operating system will determine when threads actually start running.
To give threads a reasonable chance of running at the same time, use a "startLatch" as shown in the code below.

The demo-code below is runnable and should give a good idea on how you can make the reader-thread wait for more input from the writer-thread.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ReadWhileWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try {
            CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
            Path testFile = Paths.get("test-read-while-write.txt");
            testFile.toFile().delete();
            int fakeSlowWriteMs = 100; // waiting time in milliseconds between writes. 

            CountDownLatch testFileExists = new CountDownLatch(1);
            AtomicInteger bytesWritten = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicBoolean writeFinished = new AtomicBoolean();

            // Writer
            executor.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    // Make sure reader and writer start at the same time
                    startLatch.countDown();
                    if (!startLatch.await(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Bogus reader start.");
                    }
                    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(testFile)) {
                        testFileExists.countDown();
                        int maxLoops = 10;
                        IntStream.range(0, maxLoops).forEach(i -> {
                            byte[] msg = ("hello " + i + "\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            try {
                                out.write(msg);
                                out.flush();
                                bytesWritten.addAndGet(msg.length);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (fakeSlowWriteMs > 0 && i < maxLoops - 1) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(fakeSlowWriteMs);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                writeFinished.set(true);
            });
            // Reader
            CountDownLatch doneLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            executor.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    // Make sure reader and writer start at the same time
                    startLatch.countDown();
                    if (!startLatch.await(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Bogus writer start.");
                    }
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int bytesRequired = 1; // Number of bytes read from file in one go.
                    int maxWaitTimeMs = 1000;
                    if (!testFileExists.await(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Writer did not open file for reading within 500 ms.");
                    }
                    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(testFile)) {
                        boolean eof = false;
                        while (!eof) {
                            if (!writeFinished.get()) {
                                if (bytesWritten.get() - bytesRead < bytesRequired) {
                                    int sleepTimeTotal = 0;
                                    while (!writeFinished.get()) {
                                        Thread.sleep(1);
                                        if (bytesWritten.get() - bytesRead >= bytesRequired) {
                                            break; // break the waiting loop, read the available bytes.
                                        }
                                        sleepTimeTotal += 1;
                                        if (sleepTimeTotal >= maxWaitTimeMs) {
                                            throw new RuntimeException("No bytes available to read within waiting time.");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            int b = in.read();
                            bytesRead += 1;
                            if (b < 0) {
                                eof = true;
                            } else {
                                System.out.print( (char) b);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                doneLatch.countDown();
            });
            if (!doneLatch.await(3000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Reader and writer did not finish within 3 seconds.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("\nFinished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: > But in general, you would be much better off using a queue and following the producer/consumer pattern.
Generally I agree but I chose this approach because the amount of data may be big and I want to store it in a file anyway.

The solution with ```Atomic``` variables is good, I guess it would work with ```volatile``` variables too as long as there is only one reader and one writer

Comment: @MaxZofal `volatile boolean` could replace the `AtomicBoolean`, but for the `AtomicInteger` there is the case of "reading a partial write". In practise there is never a partial read on an `int` on a 32/64 bit system, but that is not general knowledge and `AtomicInteger` will make sure that "reading a partial write" never happens (just like with `AtomicLong` etc), as per specification/documentation.